# How to use spyk

Tags: kotlin, mockk

I need to verify that a method has been called on an object. So I make a spy of this object:

```
obj = spyk(obj)
```

And then I verify that a method has been called:

```
verify(exactly = 1) { obj.f(3) }
```

The test fails with the following error message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: call 1 of 1: obj(#2).f(eq(3))) was not called.
```

However I can clearly see the method `f` being called:

1. I can break in that method in debug mode
2. I print out `hello world from f()` in that method and see it being printed.

How do I use spies correctly in mockk?

P.S.

I tried doing `val obj = spyk(obj())` but I get `lateinit has not been initialized error` because I need to set a parameter in `obj` as so:

```
obj.setDependency(friend)
```

But in the case where I first do `val obj = spyk(obj())` and then call `obj.setDependency(friend)` like I explained above I end up with a `lateinit has not been initialized error`

Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you show the whole test?

Answer (score 0):

You can mock an object with Spyk, which is what I think you were trying to do with spyk(obj()):

Say you have the following viewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
     myUseCase1: MyUseCase1,
     myRepository: MyRepository
) : ViewModel {

......

     fun myFun(value: Boolean) { 
         if (value) {
              myUseCase1.doSomething()
              doSomethingElse()
         }
     }

     private fun doSomethingElse() {
       //do something
     }
}
```

You can mock the object:

```
class MyViewModelTest {

     @Mockk
     val myUseCase1: MyUseCase1

     @Mockk
     val myRepository: MyRepository

     private lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel

     @Before
     fun setUp() { 
          MockKAnnotations.init(relaxed = true)
          val viewModel = spyk(
                MyViewModel(
                   myUseCase1,
                   myRepository
                ),
                recordPrivateCalls = true
          )
     }

     @Test
     fun test1() { 
          viewModel.myFun(true)
          verify { myUseCase1.doSomething() }
          verify { viewModel.doSomethingElse() }
     }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your case, I don't understand this part `obj = spyk(obj)`. What are you doing here? I think this part don't even compile.

You receive `lateinit has not been initialized error` because `spyk(obj())` calls real constructor. If your object has dependencies, you have to create them too or pass `mockk` instead of them.

According to the documentation:

> Note: the spy object is a copy of a passed object.

You have to create this object like a normal object, so all dependencies have to be filled.

I am using spyk in this way, let me show you a quick example.

```
    fun `should call method testMethod`() {
    val spy = spyk<TestClass>()

    spy.testMethod(1)

    verify (exactly = 1) { spy.testMethod(1) }
}
```